# Input Lines of Data in Page Template Form

Tags: plone

I have a CMF Action to edit custom archetype type metadata, where author is one of the fields to be edited. The following code in editing form template is for StringFiled:

```
<input type="text"
       name="new_author:list"
       value="author"
       size="40"
       tal:condition="canModifyItem"
       tal:attributes="value obj/getAuthor;
       id string:${item}_author;" />
```

If I change the field from 'author' to 'authors', using LinesField instead of StringField, how can I update the template for input multiple lines of data (one name per line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use a textarea, instead of input tag, and parse the input data through a split('/n') in order to get a list of inputed lines.

also,
instead of tal:attributes="value... you have to use tal:content="obj/getAuthor"

hth